# Steps to install NASM offline on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nasm

I tried these 2 packages

1. nasm-2.12.01-xdoc.tar.xz
2. nasm-2.10.05-1.tar.bz2

I installed per the instruction of the first package and the directory is not created with filename and `./configure` command says configure not present

The second package installed, when I enter command `whereis nasm` says:

```
/opt/usr/bin/nasm
```

When I enter `nasm` at the command line it says the program `nasm` is currently not installed.

I'm looking for the steps to properly install *NASM*.

If it need to uninstall first then please provide the steps to do that.

Comment: Thanx      @MichaelPetch     it worked.                   Thank you very much

Comment: If the answer helped and answered your question please consider `accepting the answer`. More information on the hows and whys of accepting an answer can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 11):

If you have installed *NASM* via a Ubuntu package manager already, then you can remove it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove nasm
hash -d nasm
```

The latest version on the *NASM* site is at this time is [2.14.02](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.14.02/). To install it from the command line you can do:

```
wget http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.14.02/nasm-2.14.02.tar.bz2
tar xfj nasm-2.14.02.tar.bz2
cd nasm-2.14.02/
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ 
make 
sudo make install
hash -d nasm
```

You should then be able to run:

```
nasm -v
```

Comment: Super helpful. I needed the new stable version (2.16.01) on Ubuntu 22.04.3 because I couldn't debug with the files that were created by older version.  Thanks for all the steps that helped me get it built and installed.

Comment: @Michael Petch -- this worked for me too, installing 2.16.01.  Thank you very much.