# GDB does not show source lines in Docker container

Tags: docker, gdb, nasm

I am running a program in a Docker container for the first time.  The program is an .exe written in C that calls a shared object written in NASM.  The programs were written and debugged (with GDB) outside of the container.

When the container starts I install  GCC, NASM, GDB:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdb
apt-get update && apt-get install -y nasm
```

Inside the Docker container I run GDB from a shell script, as I normally do.  The script assembles and links NASM, then calls the .exe file with GDB.  NASM is assembled with dwarf symbols:  nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf Complex_Calc_YZ.asm.

The problem is that GDB shows the source code lines in the C program when I step through, but inside the NASM program the source lines do not show.  The source file is included in the working directory, as I always do.  The necessary data files are all located in volume mounts on the host file system.

So I have followed the setup I have been using for a long time, but running it in a Docker container for the first time I have this problem.

Is there something else I should do when I install GDB in a Docker container?

Thanks very much for any help on this.

Comment: Are the versions of nasm the same inside and outside the container?

Comment: @Andrew:  You're on the right path.  See the answer  posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, so I'm posting the solution here.  It was solved by a very helpful answer by Peter Cordes at [GDB does not load source lines from NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694342/gdb-does-not-load-source-lines-from-nasm).

Ubuntu 22.04 installs NASM 2.15.05 when using apt install nasm.  But there is a known bug on 2.15.05 that breaks DWARF debug symbols.  The bug was fixed in 2.16.01, see https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdocc.html.

The solution was to install NASM 2.16.01 from source.  I did that by following very useful instructions from Michael Petch at [Steps to install NASM offline on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144930/steps-to-install-nasm-offline-on-ubuntu).  These are his instructions, updated to download and install 2.16.01.

```
sudo apt-get remove nasm
hash -d nasm

wget http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.16.01/nasm-2.16.01.tar.bz2
tar xfj nasm-2.16.01.tar.bz2
cd nasm-2.16.01/
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ 
make 
sudo make install
hash -d nasm
```

Now I can see the source lines when I step through the NASM file.  Note that this must be done inside the container, not on the host.